# BERT model not giving loss or logits when training in an epoch

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, bert-language-model

I'm trying to train the model. This is the epoch loop

```py
seed_val = 17
random.seed(seed_val)
np.random.seed(seed_val)
torch.manual_seed(seed_val)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed_val)

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
# model.to(device)

training_stats = []

for epoch_i in range(0, epochs):

    print("")
    print('======== Epoch {:} / {:} ========'.format(epoch_i + 1, epochs))
    print('Training...')

    # Reset the total loss for this epoch.
    total_train_loss = 0

    model.train()

    # For each batch of training data...
    for step, batch in enumerate(dataloader_train):

        b_input_ids = batch[0].to(device)
        b_input_mask = batch[1].to(device)
        b_labels = batch[2].to(device)

        model.zero_grad()

        loss, logits = model(b_input_ids,
                             token_type_ids=None,
                             attention_mask=b_input_mask,
                             labels=b_labels)
        print(loss)
        print(logits)
        total_train_loss += loss.item()
```

the output is as follows:

```py
======== Epoch 1 / 4 ========
Training...
loss
logits
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\frase\BERT.py", line 152, in <module>
    total_train_loss += loss.item()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'item'
```

I don't get why it just prints the loss and logits and not the actual loss value? I have looked how other people have done it and this is exactly how they have coded it. I don't get why it doesn't give me the value. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the result of `print(output)` where `output = model(b_input_ids, token_type_ids=None, attention_mask=b_input_mask, labels=b_labels)`?

Comment: Can you also please tell which pre-trained model you have loaded ?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem. Then I tried:

```
output = model(b_input_ids, token_type_ids=None, attention_mask=b_input_mask, labels=b_labels)
loss = output[0]
logits = output[1]
```

It kind of worked for me because models do not return `tuples` anymore but specific output objects.